# Holomorphic Function on Disk

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $f$ be holomorphic function on unit disk and it is continuous on boundary of the disk.

It is known that $f$ is constant and equal to zero if $f$ is vanishing on sub-arc of boundary (Maximum Principle + Reflection theorem).

Also, if real part $Ref$ is vanishing on whole boundary then we have $f$ is constant (by open mapping thm + harmonic function's maximum principle).

However, can we construct a "non-constant" such function $f$ satisfying real part $Ref$ is vanishing only on sub-arc of boundary?

Comment: Consider a biholomorphic map from the unit disk to a rectangle with one edge on the imaginary axis, the existence of it is implied by Riemann mapping theorem.

Comment: *To prof. Alexandre Eremenko,* I have read the reference that you provided but it just makes sure that $f$ is holomorphic on disk and $u$ is continuous on disk and its boundary as well as $v$ is the harmonic conjugate. So, how to show $f$ is continuous on the boundary? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, of course. Take a harmonic function $u$ which is zero on some arc, but not identically equal to 0. This is possible, because the Dirichlet problem is solvable for the disk. Then attach to it a conjugate harmonic function $v$, and set $f=u+iv$.

Alternative argument: consider a region $D$ whose boundary is nice and contains a piece of the imaginary line. Then consider a conformal map $f$ of the disk onto $D$.

Comment: Should $u$ be merely continuous on the arc? A harmonic function that vanishes on a stretch of arc vanishes everywhere.

Comment: Copied from an answer-post by [Alfred](http://mathoverflow.net/users/69200/alfred): *To prof. Alexandre Eremenko*,

From your first answer, Is it that $f$ holomorphic on disk and continuous on the boundary?

Comment: Yes, if the boundary value of $u$ is smooth enough, for example, infinitely smooth. See any book on harmnic analysis, for example Zygmunt, Trig series.

Comment: Another one from the same source: "*To prof. Alexandre Eremenko,*

I have read the reference that you provided but it just makes sure that $f$ is holomorphic on disk and $u$ is continuous on disk and its boundary as well as $v$ is the harmonic conjugate.

So, how to show $f$ is continuous on the boundary? Thank you.
"

Comment: If $u$ is smooth in the closed disk then $v$ is smooth in the closed disk. In particular,  $v$ is continuous. So $f=u+iv$ is continuous.